# how to call a bash common routine from another bash script . the current shell is ksh

Tags: bash, ksh

I am receiving a error while executing the code . **My current shell is ksh.**

```
cat /home/ravi/user.txt
ravi|12345677|<tr>ravi@ymail.com</tr>
```

file1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
. /file2.sh
myfile="/home/ravi/user.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do 
  split_a_line "$line"
done  < $myfile
```

### file2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
split_a_line()
{
IFS=\|  read -a v_array <<< "$1"
echo ${v_array[0]}
}
```

I am executing my script like ./file1.sh 
i am receiving following error 
**ksh: syntax error: `<' unexpected**`

when i keeping my code in the same file the script is working but when i keep in two different files the script is throwing error.

i believe the script is executing in ksh shell.
I have other some other code as well in file1.sh which is compatible with ksh shell. Do i need to change the code in file2.sh to ksh compatible or is there any other work around .

Thanks in advance

Comment: You aren't escaping the pipe in `split_a_line`; it's `IFS=\| read -a ...`

Comment: Also, check your file permissions and the like. `./file1.sh` should honor the shebang and invoke bash **if** the script is executable, **if** there aren't hidden characters on leading newlines messing up the shebang, &c.

Comment: `my code is working sometimes` are corner cases which will yield unexpected horrible results at times. You may start with [shell check](http://www.shellcheck.net)

Comment: while posting the question i made a typo error i am escaping the pipe

Comment: (...by contrast, the shebang on `file2.sh` isn't going to be honored -- and, like all shell libraries, you should give it an extension specific to the shell it's written for, in this case `file2.bash`; **commands**, by contrast, shouldn't have extensions at all -- so `file1` should be named just that, with no `.sh`).

Comment: @user3471254, ...part of asking a good question is verifying that the exact text of code included in that question is sufficient for someone else to reproduce the problem you're asking about -- as given at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Having a typo in code in the question is proof positive that you haven't gone through those steps.

Comment: @user3471254, ...in an ideal world, that means also documenting other steps you've taken, such as setting file permissions, involved in the process of setting up to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Try little steps, like adding `echo "par1=$1"` before reading v_array and calling `split_a_line "arg1|arg2|arg3"`.